# Svelte flickering when adding new elements to scroll

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

- REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/bf3db76cdd294b3882398bf4952f820f?version=3.55.0

Code:

`App.svelte`

```js
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import InfiniteScroll from './InfiniteScroll.svelte';
    
    // if the api (like in this example) just have a simple numeric pagination
  let page = 1;
    // but most likely, you'll have to store a token to fetch the next page
    let nextUrl = '';
    // store all the data here.
    let data = [];
    // store the new batch of data here.
    let newBatch = [];
    
    async function fetchData() {
        const response = await fetch(`https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=${page}&limit=2`);
        newBatch = await response.json();
        console.log(newBatch);
    };
    
    onMount(()=> {
        // load first batch onMount
        fetchData();
    })

  $: data = [
        ...data,
    ...newBatch
  ];
</script>

<div class="parent">
    {#each data as d (d.id)}
        <div class="children">
            <img class="cover" src={d.download_url} alt="download"/>
        </div>
    {/each}
    <InfiniteScroll
      hasMore={newBatch.length}
      threshold={100}
      on:loadMore={() => {page++; fetchData()}}
    />
</div>

<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    
    .parent {
        max-height: 100vh;
        overflow-y: auto;
        scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .children {
        position: relative;
        background-color: black;
        min-height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        color: white;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 64px;
        scroll-snap-align: center;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    }
    
    .cover {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-size: cover;
        max-height: 100vh;
    }
</style>
```

`InfiniteScroll.svelte`

```js
<script>
  import { onMount, onDestroy, createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";

  export let threshold = 0;
  export let horizontal = false;
  export let elementScroll;
  export let hasMore = true;

  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
  let isLoadMore = false;
  let component;

  $: {
    if (component || elementScroll) {
      const element = elementScroll ? elementScroll : component.parentNode;

      element.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
      element.addEventListener("resize", onScroll);
    }
  }

  const onScroll = e => {
    const element = e.target;

    const offset = horizontal
      ? e.target.scrollWidth - e.target.clientWidth - e.target.scrollLeft
      : e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.clientHeight - e.target.scrollTop;

    if (offset <= threshold) {
      if (!isLoadMore && hasMore) {
        dispatch("loadMore");
      }
      isLoadMore = true;
    } else {
      isLoadMore = false;
    }
  };

  onDestroy(() => {
    if (component || elementScroll) {
      const element = elementScroll ? elementScroll : component.parentNode;

      element.removeEventListener("scroll", null);
      element.removeEventListener("resize", null);
    }
  });
</script>

<div bind:this={component} style="width:0px" />
```

When we scroll to the bottom of the list, the screen flickers and displays the previous element for a moment of time.

Encountering this trouble when trying to implement infinite scrolling, please check the repl. Thanks!

Comment: You are using images that first have to load, of course there will be some flickering. Is that your issue? If not, create a proper minimal example that shows the issue without using images.

Comment: @H.B. Yes, I removed the images and it still happens. This is a different kind of flickering. Can you see the repl once again? I have updated it.

Comment: I think `scroll-snap-type` is causing the problem

Comment: @Corrl Gosh, thanks for that. It does go away when I remove `scroll-snap-type`. Is there any alternative to that?

Comment: `InfiniteScroll` should not be a component by the way. This is something that [actions](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action) are made for.

Comment: @H.B. Thanks a lot for that, that is exactly the issue. I use `svelte-inview` library and action `inview` and it works.

Comment: If you found a working solution, why not share it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @H.B.

> InfiniteScroll should not be a component by the way. This is something
> that  actions are made for.

Answer REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/cb9b9e77febb496c9f9af118dd077cb6?version=3.55.0

Used `svelte-inview` library and `inview` action.

Code

`App.svelte`

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { inview } from 'svelte-inview';
    
    // if the api (like in this example) just have a simple numeric pagination
  let page = 0;
    // but most likely, you'll have to store a token to fetch the next page
    let nextUrl = '';
    // store all the data here.
    let data = [];
    // store the new batch of data here.
    let newBatch = [];
    // no more data
    let noMoreData = false;
    
    async function fetchData() {
        const response = await fetch(`https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=${page}&limit=2`);
        newBatch = await response.json();
        console.log(newBatch);
    };
    
    onMount(()=> {
        // load first batch onMount
        // fetchData();
    })
    
    let visible = true;

  $: data = [
        ...data,
    ...newBatch
  ];
</script>

<div class="parent">
    {#each data as d (d.id)}
        <div class="children">
                <span class="center">{d.id}</span>
        </div>
    {/each}
    <div use:inview={{}} style="height: 10px;" on:change={(e) => {
        if (e.detail.inView && !noMoreData) {
            page++;
            fetchData();
        }
    }}></div>
</div>

<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    
    .parent {
        max-height: 100vh;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .children {
        position: relative;
        background-color: black;
        min-height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        color: white;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 64px;
        scroll-snap-align: center;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    }
    
    .cover {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-size: cover;
        max-height: 100vh;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Better also include the code from the Repl since it might be unavailable or break